# Как правильно опубликовать приложение в PlayMarket, чтоб оно было доступно только по ссылке?

Tags: android, google-play

Есть приложение которое я хочу опубликовать, но которое должно быть доступно только по сслыке. Я видел, что есть возможность опубликовать таким образом

https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-publish-private-apps-in-google-play/

Но это не совсем, то что мне нужно так как таким образом мне нужно добавлять id как сказано в этом пункте

> Input the organization ID and name for each organization you wish to publish the app to. Click Add.

Так же есть возможность опубликовать приложение в альфа или бета версии, но это тоже не совсем то что нужно так как в альфа я могу добавить до 20 шерингов и в бете до 200

Вопрос:) как правильно выполнить вот такую публикацию которая будет доступна по ссылке без всяких ограничений?

Comment: я возможно задам очень глупый вопрос - но что за ссылка, она будет где-то на каком-то сайте находится грубо говоря и будет переходить на страницу маркета или это маркете ссылка будет?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko нет, я имею ввиду ссылка на скачивание приложения. Чтоб его не было в общем доступе не плей маркете, а чтоб только доступ на скачивание был у тех кому я отправил такую ссылку

Comment: Можно по-моему на маркете регулировать доступность приложения, а дальше ссылку уже раздавать вручную

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, это то что я ищу

Comment: Внутреннее тестирование не устоит? Приложение будет доступно только тем, кого вы добавите в тестеры. То бишь человек говорит вам свой эмайл, вы ему высылаете приглашение

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий Согласно дукументации там не так все просто https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479 нужно еще попросить пользователя открыть шаринг, потом еще какой то сертификат загрузить,,, Если ты тестер, то это не проблема, но ссылка будет высылаться пользователям и это не совсем приемлемо

Comment: Исходя из Ваших требований плеймаркет Вам не подойдёт. Как вариант можно положить апк на своём сервере, либо на гугл диске(включив доступ по ссылке).

Comment: То о чем вы говорите - это какие-то узкие фичи. Вообще работает очень просто, вы заливаете на внутреннее тестирование, в список тестеров добавляете адреса, человек получает письмо, соглашается и получает ссылку на приложение в гуглплее. Все ставится, все работает. Автообновления не уверен что работают, но вручную в плеймаркете можно обновить точно

Comment: Я использовал внутреннее тестирование, никаких "просьб к пользователю открыть шаринг или сертификат загрузить" не нужно, все отлично сделано как и в закрытой альфа версии. Пользователь просматривает только стартовое окно.